# Set up constructor in C# abstraction

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class, scope

Consider the following **very basic** C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                int num = random.Next(1000);
                string it_type;

                if (num == 666)
                {
                    System.Console.Write("Antichrist/satanistic trips get. Enjoy! ");
                    JonSkeet technician = new JonSkeet(); // Needs more Super::$tatic
                    technician.setup();
                    it_type = technician.getITType();
                }
                else
                {
                    Whisperity technician = new Whisperity();
                    technician.setup();
                    it_type = technician.getITType();
                }

                System.Console.WriteLine(it_type + "... Prepare for next iteration.");
            }

            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    abstract public class ITTechnician
    {
        protected string itt_type = "Noname person.";
        protected bool isJonSkeet = false;

        public string getITType()
        {
            return this.itt_type;
        }

        abstract public void setup();
    }

    public class JonSkeet : ITTechnician
    {
        public override void setup()
        {
            this.itt_type = "Jon Skeet";
            this.isJonSkeet = true;
        }
    }

    public class Whisperity : ITTechnician
    {
        public override void setup()
        {
            this.itt_type = "Whisperity";
            this.isJonSkeet = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I be able to set up a constructor in a way that the abstract class (`abstract public void`?) would require it and that I don't have to call `technician.setup();` because the constructor takes care of setting the two internal variables. If I call the class functions the same name as the class itself, I get the following error:

> Error 1 'Whisperity': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing

Also, my other question would be about optimization. Is there a way to define `technician` outside the `if` construct so something like the following could be executed: (This would omit having the `classType technician = new classType();` lines twice, or is it unbypassable in C#?)

```
string it_type;
// Register 'technician' as a variable here.
if (num = 666)
{
    technician = new JonSkeet();
}
else
{
    technician = new Whisperity();
}

it_type = technician.getITType();
System.Console.WriteLine(it_type + "...");
```

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: You can't force a derived class to implement a consructor, but you *can* force it to invoke a constructor in the abstract class.  If the abstract class has no default constructor, a subclass *must* explicitly invoke a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your Question**

You can provide a constructor with parameters in the abstract class.

```
abstract public class ITTechnician
{
    public ITTechnician(string itt_type, bool isJonSkeet)
    {
        this.itt_type = itt_type;
        this.isJonSkeet = isJonSkeet;
    }
}
```

To construct a JonSkeet (if only it were so easy!)

```
JonSkeet jon = new JonSkeet("Jon Skeet", true);
```

**Advice on Class Design**

On a side note, I know this is a sample question, but you are not using object orientation well if a base class holds information that would differentiate classes that inherit from it.

Specifically this design would lead you to do things like

```
ITTechnician itt = GetSomeInstance();

if (itt.IsJonSkeet)
{
    BehaviorA();
else
{
    BehaviorB();
}
```

It is far cleaner to do something like

```
abstract public class ITTechnician
{
    public abstract void Behavior();
    // ...
}

public class JonSkeet
{
    public override Behavior()
    {
        // Do awesome things
    }
}
```

which allows the above code to be written as

```
ITTechnician itt = GetSomeInstance();
itt.Behavior();
```

Comment: I believe you can also define a default constructor in an abstract class which is called naturally by its descendants. You could possibly use this as a fallback if the descendants do not call custom constructors!?

Comment: @MatthewLayton: If you have an initialization contract, providing a default constructor allows a subclass to violate that contract and not initialize the type property.  You get the same effect using the original *setup* method.  A subclass could just decide not to call *setup* and leave the object in an improperly initialized state.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I be able to set up a constructor in a way that the abstract
>   class would require it and that I don't have to call
>   technician.setup()

You don't need construct your logic to force the behavior of `abstract` class, but vice versa. `Abstract` class defines a stuf that has to be followed by the child.

If you create a simple *parametless* ctor in `abstract` class, which initializes the variables you need, whenever the `child` object will be constructed, the default ctor of `abstract` will be called before, so intialization will be executed.

To be more clear:

```
public class Child : Base 
{

    public Child(int x){
     "Child".Dump();
    }
}

public abstract class Base
{

    public Base() {

        //INIT VARIABLES HERE
       "Base".Dump();
    }
}
```

using these constructs like

`vaar ch = new Child();` produces the result

```
"Base"
"Child"
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To discover a type at runtime, use `GetType()`. There's no need to create your own type string field.

The only thing that varies other than the intrinsic type in your class structure is `IsJonSkeet`. We can use a .NET property to implement this, which is a more modern and expressive way when compared to traditional private/protected fields with a Getter and maybe a Setter.

```
abstract public class ITTechnician
{
    public bool IsJonSkeet { get; protected set; }
    protected ITTechnician()
    {
        this.IsJonSkeet = false;
    }
}

public class JonSkeet : ITTechnician
{
    public JonSkeet()
    {
        this.IsJonSkeet = true;
    }
}

public class Whisperity : ITTechnician
{
}
```

Now that your itt_type string field has been removed, Whisperity is the same as the base class, so there's no need for a constructor to do any initialisation - it will pick up the IsJonSkeet value of its parent automatically.

+1 for Eric J's class design tips, too. You should use the design of your hierarchy to encapsulate what varies and this makes your calling code much more transparent and the codebase easier to expand on in the future.